# Unable to find posts awaiting review

Tags: support, status-completed

I noted that I currently have some posts awaiting review:

[image]

In the past, they were generally approvals for suggested edits.

Instead, I noted that clicking on that notification, I don't have anything to do:

[image]

I guess this behavior could be related to the [Access To Moderator Tools](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) privilege that I recently earned, but I wasn't able to find any other place for *answering* to the three notifications mentioned above.

I tried to have a look at the [/tools](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tools) link, but all the stuff there seems to be informational.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not certain, but I suspect that this may be related to [What does the number next to the review link in the top bar actually mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251659) from Meta Stack Exchange.

For me there are often a few reviews numbered but not present in the review queue on the sites that I frequent.  I've always assumed that it is mainly down to caching.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I agree with you (even if this behavior is a bit frustrating).